# How can I save additional messages that would normally be excluded by Loglevel in case of errors

Tags: serilog

I have a basic serilog-usage-scenario: Logging messages from an Web-Application. In production I set the log-level to "information".

Now my question: Is it possible to write the last ~100 debug/trace messages to the log after an error occurs, so that I have a short history of detailed messages before the error occurred. This would keep my log clean and gives me enough informations to track errors.

I created such a mechanism years ago for another application/logging-framework, but I'm curious if thats already possible with Serilog.

If not, where in the pipeline would be the place to implement such logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that Serilog has out-of-the-box, but it would be possible to implement by writing a [custom sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink) that *wraps* all other sinks and caches the most recent ~100 `Debug` messages and forwards them to the sinks when an `Error` message occurs.

You might want to look at the code of [Serilog.Sinks.Async](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) for inspiration, as it shows you a way of wrapping multiple sinks into one.